# How to incorporate Google's Web Starter Kit in a Middleman project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html5boilerplate, middleman, google-web-starter-kit

Just found the [Google's New Web Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/starter-kit/) today and I like it much.

BUT, how would I go about incorporating the baseline HTML, CSS/SASS, JS, etc... into a [Middleman](https://middlemanapp.com/) project?

I would imagine the answer would also apply to other frameworks like ASP.NET MVC, Ruby on Rails, etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the steps I'm doing when incorporating framework to middleman.

- **Base HTML**, I convert the base HTML to `.haml` and set this as my layout template.
- **Sass, JS, etc**, put them in their respective directories (`images/`, `stylesheets/`)

Have a look at [Bootstrap starter kit for Middleman](https://github.com/novemberkilo/middleman-twitter-bootstrap) to give you an idea how to use a framework in Middleman. Hope this helps ;)